# What is the entitlement for a Mac App to use CoreWLAN to access Wi-Fi in the Sandbox?

Tags: macos, wifi, sandbox

Bluetooth for e.g. is `com.apple.security.device.bluetooth`.

Apple does not currently document this particular entitlement in the [Entitlement Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html)

Comment: Do you mean just connecting to servers on the Internet? It seems to be `com.apple.security.network.client`. If your app wants to _configure_ Wi-Fi, that's a different story (and I don't know which key to use for that).

Comment: No, need to use the CoreWLAN API, clarified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of WWDC 18 and `CoreWLAN.framework` was allowed into the sandbox in both `macOS 10.13` and `10.14`. But note that the location entitlement is required to get the `BSSID` information from a Wi-Fi Scan.

The specific entitlements for older versions of `macOS` can be found by using the `codesign` tool:

```
$ codesign -d --entitlements :- /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreWLANKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/WiFiProxy.xpc/Contents/MacOS/WiFiProxy
Executable=/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreWLANKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/WiFiProxy.xpc/Contents/MacOS/WiFiProxy
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.anqp</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.associate</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.events</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.events.private</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.ibss</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.priority.id</key>
    <string>wifi_menu_extra</string>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.priority.internal</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.scan</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.set_power</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.tether.browse</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.tether.connect</key>
    <true/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>apple</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```